# Connecting HTML select options with two way binding Angular2+

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-directive, two-way-binding

I am making a feature in my app that changes the color of my toolbar in Angular.

For this I created a directive that has a parameter of color string.

The directive works fine when I hardcode the value that I want,

Now I want to use a select option to assign the value to the directive dynamically.

Im doing so currently through click event. My method is collecting my value from the option and assigning it to the value of my toolBarColor variable.

I have checked through the inspection and saw that my method successfully collects the value and assigns it to the variable that is connected to my directive.

I have also tried with the [ngValue] and ngModel route but have not had success yet.

Below is my code.

```
<select class="form-control" (click)="colorSelect(colorChosen)" [(ngModel)]="toolbarColor">
  <option *ngFor="let color of themeColors" value="{{color}}">{{color}}</option>
</select>
```

my component contains this method

```
colorSelect(color: string){
    this.toolbarColor = color;
  }
```

toolbar is simply an empty string variable.

directive code is as such.

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myColorPicker]'
})
export class ColorPickerDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() myColorPicker: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 
  }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 this.elRef.nativeElement.style.background = this.myColorPicker;
  }

}
```

this is the implementation of the directive in my toolbar

```
<div class="toolbar" role="banner" myColorPicker={{toolbarColor}}>
```

Comment: You need to provide more code related to directive, can you please create a basic stackblitz instance of your code?

Comment: Sadly stackblitz is having problems generating the repo instance. says its missing my package.json file which is a bug because it exist in the repo. I will add my directive code to initial question.

Comment: Can you please also add code how and where are you using this directive in template?

Comment: I just inserted it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the background, when the Input to your directive changes. There are two possible solutions.

**1. Use a setter with a backing variable like this:**

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myColorPicker]'
})
export class ColorPickerDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input()
  set myColorPicker(val: string) {
      this._myColorPicker = val;
      updateBackground();
  }
  _myColorPicker!: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     updateBackground();
  }

  updateBackground() {
     this.elRef.nativeElement.style.background = this._myColorPicker;
  }
}
```

**2. use the ngOnChanges event like this:**

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myColorPicker]'
})
export class ColorPickerDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() myColorPicker: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     updateBackground();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     updateBakground(); // I am not sure if myColorPicker contains the new value at this point. If not you need to read the new value from the changes object
  }

  updateBackground() {
     this.elRef.nativeElement.style.background = this.myColorPicker;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right the change was only happening onInit but not onChanges. I tried to add onChanges method in the component instead of in the directive. Graci!